# SQL Datetime query remove seconds

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am selecting three columns from my database with

`$sql = "SELECT lnumber,violation,datetime FROM violators WHERE lnumber='".$lnumber."'";`

and parsing the result into JSONArray and I am getting this result

```
{"lnumber":"2","violation":"Beating the red light","datetime":"2017-10-15 13:02:34"}
```

Now what I want to do is how can I parse the "**datetime**" field without the seconds?

Here is the full code:

```
$sql = "SELECT lnumber,violation,datetime FROM violators WHERE lnumber='".$lnumber."'";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($lnumber, $violation, $datetime);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
$temp = [
'lnumber'=>$lnumber,
'violation'=>$violation,
'datetime'=>$datetime
];  
array_push($result, $temp);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-10-15 13:52:35", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")
```

Use ***%H*** for 2 digit 24 hour format (e.g. 08) or ***%k*** for 1 digit.

**Reference:**
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

**Try it here:**
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_date_format

Comment: How do I achieve this? By doing this? `$sql = "SELECT lnumber,violation,DATE_FORMAT("2017-10-15 13:52:35", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")  FROM violators WHERE lnumber='".$lnumber."'";` ? Is this right?

Comment: Yes, but replace the date text with your datetime table column like this:

DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-10-15 13:02:34", "%Y-%m-%d %h:%m");
=> 2017-10-15 01:10
```

MySQL DATE_FORMAT https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp
This is if you want to get rid of the seconds during the data fetch.